# Changes required in existing Web Application to access in Smart phones/Tablet computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

I have a ASP.NET Web Application. I want to access this application in Smart phones and tablet computer. So please help me on this. What are the changes required?

Comment: To identify what needs to be changed, try the application on every device, note down what doesn't work and fix it. Rinse and repeat for every device.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question could range from nothing to everything.  At the end of the day, it all depends on what you existing app looks like in a target mobile device (iPad, Android, etc).  If your existing app looks and functions properly, then you don't have to do anything.  If not, well, you figure out what's wrong and make it work.

Your question really isn't suited for StackOverflow because it is way to broad and impossible to answer.

Comment: I am getting browser compatibility issue.

Comment: @PintuYadav: That's expected. Check out JQuery Mobile.  Chances are you have to build another site that's optimized for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net applications can run in web browsers, including the ones that come with smart phones and tablets. The main concern would be the various screen sizes of the various devices. Because they vary so much, a good design concept for your asp.net application would be to layout content in a way it can adapt to the screen size.

The best technology for this within an asp.net application, especially for an application that was already built, would be to implement style sheets (.css)

Look at these styles as an example:

`float`, `clear`, `max-width` and `max-height`

Check these and other styles at: http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Now, there is also the concept of having your asp.net application detect which device is being used and then generate UI code (or load .ascx controls) accordingly to provide device specific displays.

Check:

`Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice`

`Request.UserAgent` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.useragent.aspx)

However, I would only suggest using this to a minimum, because if you make a change to your UI, you won’t want to keep updating multiple instances of the UI for different devices.

A good compromise would be to build a style sheet for each group of screen sizes (smart phone, tablet, PC, etc.) and then detect which device is in use and include the respective style sheet.

NB: there are many open source projects, which could get you running more quickly with mobile development in mind. Check sourceforge.net and codeplex.com for examples.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer.This information is very use full . My project is a Dashboard project. We are using DonNetCharting controls (This is a Third party dll) for generate charts. There is a minimum use of CSS. So please suggest me, what I have to do in this?

Comment: The CSS may not be totally limited in this case. If the chart is generated as an image, you can still re-size the image to best fit the space for the device. Attach style sheets based on the device and modify the image generated via the image tag's id... example: <img id="image1" src="..." /> <style> #image1{ zoom:50%; } </style> NB: the zoom css may not be compatible with all browsers, so optionally you can hard-code a width and height via css as well.

Comment: Thanks for reply. i am not able to find open source projects that will help me on mobile development.Please share link with me.